# Polymer catch all events from child element

Tags: events, polymer

I am currently working on making lazy-loading possible together with "more-routing" in Polymer. I already got a first working implementation of lazy loading (inspired by app-router that unfortunately does not support Polymer 1.0 completely), but I have no idea how I can pass all events from the imported child element up to my lazy-loading element.

So, in my example I want the event "hi" passed from page-login to lazy-loader and from lazy-loader upwards to the element containing lazy-loader - but without having knowledge of that specific event in lazy-loader. So I need something like "catch all events fired by child element".

That's what I have :

page-login:

```
ready:function() {
                this.fire("hi");
            },
```

using lazy-loader:

```
<lazy-loader on-hi="hi" href="../pages/page-login.html" id="login" route="login"></lazy-loader>
```

calling load :

```
document.getElementById("login").load()
```

Lazy-loader (reduced version):

```
<dom-module id="lazy-loader">
<template>
    <span id="content">Loading...</span>
</template>
<script>
    window.lazyLoaded = window.lazyLoaded || [];
    Polymer({
        is: "lazy-loader",
        properties: {
            href:{
                type:String,
                value:""
            },
            element:{
                type:String,
                value:""
            }
        },
        load:function(finishFunc) {
            if(window.lazyLoaded.indexOf(this.href)===-1) {
                var that = this;
                this.importHref(this.href, function(e) {
                    window.lazyLoaded.push(that.href);
                    if(!that.element) {
                        that.element = that.href.split('/').reverse()[0];
                        that.element = that.element.split(".")[0];
                    }
                    var customElement = document.createElement(that.element);

// here I need something like "customElement.on("anyEvent")" 
// => that.fire("anyEvent")

                    Polymer.dom(that.$.content).innerHTML = "Loading done.";
                    Polymer.dom(that.$.content).appendChild(customElement);
                    Polymer.dom.flush();
                    that.fire("loaded");
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: As a side-node : I'm currently thinking of scanning the attributes given to lazy-loader starting with "on-" and adding "pass-through-listeners" for this events. I'm still open to a more generic way (without parsing attributes).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have to revoke my question - If I fire the event in the attached-handler, not in ready, it gets passed through automatically - at least in the current version of Polymer. Not sure if this is intended behavior, but for now the problem is solved. An answer still would be interesting, maybe for other cases (like event logging)